# Damage controlling deadlocks in SQL Server by switching the isolation level?

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I joined a project a while ago, which is a a few web servers and a few backend servers.

They all do CRUD things on one database.

Unfortunately, a few tables fall into a deadlock situation for a while now. We can see those victim statements via SQL Server Management Studio and its extended events feature.

Primary keys and all the necessary indexes are set already. We even rebuilt them, alot of these had fragmentations over 50%.

Thing is, there is this one table we would like to switch to the isolation level called SNAPSHOT. I know this won't solve the deadlock situation at all hence I read that write statements might block each other.

One table contains logs (login of users, tasks started and ended on the backends, yadda yadda...), the other one contains all the processes, so the backends are selecting, inserting and updating (like setting the "running" field from 0 to 1 and vice versa). While the first one for logging reasons might be good for the snapshot level, I doubt it might be recommended for the process table, as far as I understood how the snapshot leveling is working. And I am also aware that rollbacks of transactions will block the tables during the rollback process anyway.

Even the sysobjects table is getting blocked sometimes when a table has to be dropped. And I must mention that the database is ridiculously large, like many many table.

What I would like to know is, if you guys ever switched from whatever isolation level to snapshot and what challenges you had to face, or even if you changed your mind when it came to deadlock prevention and tried a different approach, like hardware upgrade, etc...

Comment: Far to general a question for anyone to be able to offer specific advice. There is a lot of information out there about deadlocks, but for large databases you frequently just have to handle the fact that you will get deadlocks from time to time and implement a client side retry or similar. Also analyse the deadlock graph and determine what the actual conflict is. If you post the deadlock graph you maybe able to get assistance.

Comment: Have you ever consider about database replication as a solution to your problem? in replication, you can use one replica with selected tables to be used for read operations. Your main database will always use for write operations.